# Is there a way to add the SVG file as inline <SVG> after request it with <IMG>?

Tags: javascript, svg

Request an **SVG** file inside the `<img>` tag to the dom. Is it possible to add inline in `<svg>` format using the same file later?

```
<script>function fn(imgdata) { ... }</script>
<img src="/path/dummy.svg" onload="fn" />
// to
<svg>...</svg>
```

Comment: What do you mean "uploading it with `<img>`?" That's not an upload, it's just a reference in a document. Are you asking "How can I convert an SVG to `data:...`?"

Comment: As a note, this is a problem that Webpack and Parcel try to solve.

Comment: sorry i fixed it, i meant "request"

Comment: What do you mean "add as inline'? What purpose would that serve? You could always AJAX get the file and inject it, but I'm not sure how that would be in any way better, or even meaningful within the context of an HTML document.